# Function of metric with a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

I'm trying to prove that given a metric space $(X, d)$, for a fixed $x\in X$, define the function $g(y)=d(x,y)$, then $g(y)$ is continuous, using triangle inequality.
My first question is that can I say $g$ is $X\to \Bbb R$?

To prove the continuity, I start with given $a\in X$, supposing that $d(y,a)<\delta ={1 \over 2}\epsilon$

Then

$d(g(y), g(a))=d(d(x,y), d(x,a))\le d(d(x,y),d(y,a))+d(d(y,a),d(x,a))< d(d(x,y),\delta)+d(\delta, d(x,a))$

But then how can I prove this is smaller than $\epsilon$ ? Or was I totally wrong with the triangle inequality approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer on your first question is: yes.

By the triangle inequality:

$g\left(z\right)=d\left(x,z\right)\leq d\left(x,y\right)+d\left(y,z\right)=g\left(y\right)+d\left(y,z\right)$
so $g\left(z\right)-g\left(y\right)\leq d\left(y,z\right)$.

By symmetry $g\left(y\right)-g\left(z\right)\leq d\left(z,y\right)=d\left(y,z\right)$.

Conclusion: $\left|g\left(y\right)-g\left(z\right)\right|\leq d\left(y,z\right)$

This ensures continuity of $g$. Do you understand why?

Comment: Is this because the LHS of your conclusion is the metric in R?

Comment: Yes. The usual topology on $\mathbb R$ is induced by the metric $d(u,v)=|u-v|$. The conclusion makes it easy to prove continuity of $g$ by means of the $\epsilon,\delta$ method. You can do it with $\delta=\epsilon$. If the topology is fixed and you want to prove continuity by means of the $\epsilon,\delta$ method then you can make use of any suitable metric that induces this topology.

Comment: Thank you. So when we say metric in R, we only mean the usual distance? No other metric is allowed?

Comment: The most common metric on $\mathbb R$ is the usual distance, but if a topology is metrizable then there are always uncountable many metrics that induce that topology. For instance you could also take $\min(|u-v|,1)$ (wich is a metric that does not exceed $1$) or $2|u-v|$.

Comment: But if the metric is not the usual distance, does the conclusion still hold?

Comment: Yes, continuity is in essence a topological property. If coincidently both topological spaces are metrizable then you can make use of that in order to prove continuity of a function with $\epsilon,\delta$ method. You are free to take any metric on domain and codomain as long as both metrics induce the topology on these spaces.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. If the metric is not usual distance, how does the last row imply continuity? Do you mean that if a function is continuous on a space, then it is continuous on this space no matter what the metric is?

Comment: Before going deeper into this: what is your definition of continuity of a function? Are you familiar with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces)? Or is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_metric_spaces) your only tool? The topologies on domain and codomain are completely determining for the question: is this function continuous? If both spaces are coincidentally metrizable then suitable metrics can be used in order to prove this continuity.